# Composite Key to navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to create a table for holding notes about a specific entity.  I have an entity called Notes that I'd like to store the PK of the entity it is referencing.  I'd like to have a composite key of the key and the table name containing the primary key.   See the example below:

```
public class Lot
{
    public int LotId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityReferenceId { get; set; }

    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string Comment {get; set; }
}
```

So in the Notes table there would be:

Id: 1 EntityReferenceId: 1  EntityType:Lot Comment: "Comment one, Lot one"

Id: 2 EntityReferenceId: 1  EntityType:Lot Comment: "Comment two, Lot one"

Id: 3 EntityReferenceId: 1  EntityType:Task Comment: "Comment one, task one"

It seems like this should be possible in the database, but I'm not having any luck with the model.  Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Note` class abstract, and create two derived classes, one for lot notes, and the other for task notes like this:

```
public abstract class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Comment {get; set; }
}

public class NoteForLot : Note
{
    public int LotId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lot Lot { get; set; }
}

public class NoteForTask : Note
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

Notice how each subclass references the correct parent object.

Your `Lot` and `Task` classes need to change to reflect the changes:

```
public class Lot
{
    public int LotId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NoteForLot> Notes { get; set; }

    public Lot()
    {
        Notes = new HashSet<NoteForLot>();
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NoteForTask> Notes { get; set; }

    public Task()
    {
        Notes = new HashSet<NoteForTask>();
    }
}
```

Entity Framework will automatically create a column in the notes table (to replace your `EntityType` property) to distinguish between the two kinds of notes. Such column will be called `Discriminator` in the database.

This feature is called Table-per-Hierarchy Inheritance. You can google it to obtain more information about it.

Comment: I've actually tried something similar to this, but it didn't fit exactly what i was trying to do.  Wouldn't this create nullable keys TaskId and NoteId?  I was trying to keep the entity reference key for all of the Foreign Keys in the same column.

Comment: While this certainly would achieve this limited example, my intention would be to have a note on many entities.  I don't feel like having many nullable columns would be a very clean succinct solution.  I could probably create reference tables i.e. Table LotNotes {FK LotId, FK NoteId}, but again this would leave me with many lookup tables.  My ideal solution would be to have a composite key for the entity and entity type.  I could filter entity type by "Lot", and then join on that key in the lot table.